# Facebook getUser returns null, but only the first time requested

Tags: facebook, authentication

This might be a very simple problem, but I can't seem to find the solution.

I'm using Facebook log-in to authenticate users. Sometimes this fails. The first time they click the 'Log-in with Facebook' button and the server does not get any data from Facebook (`$user` is empty). The interesting thing is that when the user uses the button again directly after that, everything is fine. Then, until the whole browser is closed, you can log-out and log-in perfectly without any problems.

```php
if ($user) { 
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a combination of JS and PHP SDK.

This will happen if user logs in with the JS SDK since the server side code doesn't read the cookie that was set until the page is refreshed for the first time.  You can either make an ajax call if the user successfully logs in to provide the new user id, or force the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

FYI.

I was having same problem it was because i was initializing session_start(); 
before including my fbaccess.php file.

i fixed it by changing the order to:

```
include('./fb/fbaccess.php');
session_start();
```